# XML DOM node count in Javascript for Firefox vs Internet Explorer

Tags: firefox, javascript, xls

First the code:

```
<tabulatory>
    <tab>Muzyka
            <dzial>Gitary
                <el>electric</el>
                <el>akustyczne</el>
            </dzial>
            <dzial>Pianina
                <el>klawiszowe</el>
                <el>elektroniczne</el>
                <el>zabawki</el>
            </dzial>
    </tab>
</tabulatory>
```

I use this code:

```
document.write("Elements: " + dzial[0].childNodes.length);
```

to get count of the elements just inside the dzial parent, but in Firefox it shows wrong number of 5 elements (el[0], el[1] and so on), instead of 2 or 3 like it should be accordingly.

I use Linux so no chances for Internet Explorer to work normally now.

Anyone knows how to do it, the easy way, so I don't have to use nextSibling thing (maybe).

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow, but don't duplicate it or cross-post there. Either wait for this to be migrated or delete this first before asking again there.

Comment: i didnt knew I duplicated something, FF can be tricky sometimes as the WiFi connection